# Playing a sound when turning off a circuit

Tags: switches, circuit-design, sound

For my project, I am looking to have this (mock-up) circuit play a sound, e.g. the Windows XP shutdown sound, the moment it is powered off.

I have looked at capacitors, relays, opto-couplers, and a bunch of tutorials but they all only can delay the moment the circuit is powered off or act as a timer as to how long the circuit will run, which is not what I want and I can't find anything about this anywhere.

Am I missing something fundamental or is this just not possible?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSucsx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Intentionally left out the speaker and potentially needed SD card module)

Comment: Well, you will need a way to have power after the switch is disconnected, and you will need a way to sense when the switch is toggled. A big capacitor or maybe a small battery could work to maintain power, and a pin connected to the switch output (with proper protection/level conversion) and a pulldown resistor should work to sense shutting off power. May I ask - what is the purpose of this? It might not be worth the trouble.

Comment: What you can also do is to use a software based switch. The switch could send a signal to a microcontroller which sequences power for your project as a whole, and that device can play the sound. This is probably easier than the other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a button that is sensed by your microcontroller. This triggers the sound then programmatically turns the power off to the system. Options to turn power off are: have the microcontroller go to sleep, turn your buck regulator off, a high side switch, or a relay. You'll need no supercapacitor or secondary power supply.

Comment: I knew I was missing something fundamental, now I feel dumb xD
Unfortunately I can't turn off the buck converter. Also I'm kinda new to all this so I have no idea how a high side switch works or how to incorperate a relay that not only serves as a delayed shutdown.
Now, if I'm going with the sleep mode route, I would need the Arduino to *not* automatically power up again after I disconnect and reconnect the battery and preferably push that same button as well to turn it back on. How would I go about that? Immediately set it to sleep mode and make a loop checking for the button?

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a power source needed in place of mp3 player side. You should consider using a supercapacitor which provides enough power to play the music. Since you're using Arduino consider two power sources, one from 7.2V battery (primary) and another from 5V super capacitor (secondary). Take inputs from 7.2V power sources to ADC pin and programmatically check when the primary power is going off. When primary power goes off, enable secondary power as well as trigger the music part which may be connected to a digital pin.

PS: You need to make an circuit for managing two power sources using MOSFET which is similar to how Arduino UNO manages USB and External DC jack power supply. Check reference schematic for that.